# How do I pass the template url to javascript in the ADMIN area of my theme?

Tags: wp-localize-script

I need to pass the path to a php file (located in a folder in my theme) to a JS file being used in my admin area but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

What Im trying to do, is build a page where selecting some options in a form will pass the input's value to a php script via ajax. But because JS is client side, I dont know how to point to the correct location.

I tried testing using this:

```
<?php
  wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
    $translation_array = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ), 'a_value' => '10' );
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
    wp_enqueue_script("admin", $adminDir."js/admin.js", false, "1.0");   
?>
```

with this in my admin.js:

```
 console.log(object_name.some_string);
```

But console just reads:

```
ReferenceError: object_name is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the variables from the admin.js script, and you want to be sure it works you have to

1. use as handle for `wp_localize_script` the handle of the script that have to use data
2. call `wp_localize_script` **after** that script is enqueued

   ```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
   wp_enqueue_script("admin", $adminDir."js/admin.js", false, "1.0"); 
   $translation_array = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ), 'a_value' => '10' );
   wp_localize_script( 'admin', 'object_name', $translation_array );
   ```

Using the code above and `console.log(object_name.some_string);` you will see the translated string on your console.

Read more on [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) on Codex.

Answer (score 1):

You can first register the script and enqueue it after `wp_localize_script`.

```
wp_register_script( 'script_handle', $adminDir."js/admin.js", false, '1.0' ); //register script

$translation_array = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ), 'a_value' => '10' );
wp_localize_script( 'script_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
wp_enqueue_script("script_handle"); //enqueue
```

Function Reference: [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: Why `register -> localize -> enqueue` when you can just `enqueue -> localize`? And what's the additional value of this answer toward the mine posted 3 hours before?

Comment: @G.M. There might not be additional value but i have had a similar problem some weeks before and registering the script before en-queuing it fixed it. I don't know the reason though.

Comment: Im still getting the console error I was getting before. I just copied and pasted exactly was was suggested (in both answers) and Im getting the same error :/

Comment: ah ok I got it I had to set the wp_localize_script handle to the same handle as the admin.js handle

Comment: Yes, you're right @rugbert , I just edited this in the answer to make sure others copy/paste it correctly

Comment: @gmazzap the wp_register_script function call is important if you are going to localize and enqueue the script after the 'enqueue_script' action hook is fired.  This allows the script localisation and printing to be done at a later stage such as when a shortcode is called for example.

Comment: @Aurovrata when that's the case, sure. But this is not the case. Expecially considering that OP is about admin area, where enqueuing when shortcode is used makes no sense.

Comment: @gmazzap you're right, however the original question does not specify at which point the enqueueing is being done, I can only assume it is post the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook since it apparently did not work.